# Relation between $L^{\infty}$ and $C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces

i was studying the Morrey Theorem about Sobolev Inequalities and i have a doubt: I found out about an embending from W^{1,p} to $L^{\infty}$ and an embending from W^{1,p} to  $C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ looking for Morrey result, what is the relation between these spaces? $C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ is the set of functions $u \in C(\bar{\Omega})$ which are $\alpha$-Holderian. Thanks

Comment: The $\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions are, in particular, continuous and hence, assuming that $\Omega$ is bounded, a subspace of $L^{\infty}$. Using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, you even get that the inclusion is a compact embedding.

Comment: First of all, thank you for having taken into consideration my request :) may I ask you something else or where I could find some more info about this?

Comment: Sure, shoot. :)